# opencv: blend two images with alpha mask

Tags: performance, opencv, optimization, alpha, alphablending

I'm trying to blend two images with OpenCV in the most efficient way. Currently, I have this:

```
// Input matrices to mix
cv::Mat A(w, h, CV_8UC3);
cv::Mat B(w, h, CV_8UC3);

// Mix factor
cv::Mat alpha(w, h, CV_8UC1);

// Have to multiply alpha channel for mul() function    
std::vector<cv::Mat> array{alpha, alpha, alpha};
cv::Mat alpha_multichannel;
cv::merge(array, alpha_multichannel);

cv::Mat result = A.mul(alpha_multichannel, 1./255) + B.mul(cv::Scalar(255, 255, 255) - alpha_multichannel, 1./255);
```

Currently this loops at least four times over the image (for the alpha_multichannel image, for A.mul, for B.mul and for the sum), although with a custom loop it could be done in one loop.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: what about [addWeighted](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#addweighted)?

Comment: I think (correct me if I'm wrong) addWeighted only works when using the same factor for weighting the two images for *all pixels*. In my case, I have a weighting factor *per pixel* stored in alpha.

Comment: ah.. didn't get that from the snippet. You're correct.

Comment: You can use OpenMP pragmas and it will be done in parallel. One core per channel.

Comment: @Andrey: Yes that's true. But not all platforms support OpenMP, and I cannot use the OpenCV GPU functions with OpenMP. So I'm looking for a "native" OpenCV solution.

Comment: just write the loop yourself! But in fact, OpenCV really lacks this kind of loop!

Comment: @Micka: Have a look at my comment just before: The problem is I cannot use OpenCL acceleration (for example) when using my "own" loop...

Comment: @JanRüegg would your own non-gpu code be faster or slower than 4-times-loop with gpu-support? I think it is a tradeoff: either use general purpose code that is well optimized, or use special purpose code which you would have to optimize yourself. One more possibility: have a look at opencv source code for your used functions (4-times-loop) and combine them into one special purpose openCV function, then compile openCV and use all the kind of optimizations that are included in that combined code.